# X doesn't find nvidia module when installing developer driver

Tags: 10.10, xorg, nvidia

I just downloaded the developer driver from [Nvidia's CUDA Zone](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_downloads.html). Executed it and typed in restart gdm and the it worked. However after rebooting X didn't come up ([xorg log](http://codepad.org/6DS8TVDK)), to fix it I can simply rerun the installer and the restart gdm again.

What I don't understand is where it breaks and why X11 doesn't find the module?! I removed all (I think..) of the Nvidia packages which can with Ubuntu 10.10.  I've also googled a bit and found some HOWTOs about manually installing the Nvidia driver. However all of them were for an earlier version of Ubuntu.

Please do not respond telling me I should use the proprietary Nvidia driver supplied by Ubuntu, because I need the development drivers.

Comment: According to the log, the XServer is trying to load the module `nvidia` which you most likely removed. Maybe you can fix this by using a static `xorg.conf`, if the dev-driver-module has a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written about it on the Ubuntu Forums: [HOWTO: install or uninstall nVidia drivers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1687189).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.